# How to write to zbuffer only with three.js

Tags: three.js, depth-buffer, zbuffer

I'm trying to use thee.js to only update the zbuffer (I'm using preserveDrawingBuffer to create a trace effect).
However I can't find any way to only write to the zbuffer with the standard materials, so far I've tried:

- setting the material's `visible` to false, which stops the object rendering.
- setting the material's `opacity` to 0.0, which means nothing gets rendered.

Is there a 'standard' way of doing this, or do I need to use a custom fragment shader?

Comment: check out this (kind-of-old) discussion: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1750. anyway when you set opacity 0 or visible=false the object won't render at all, so it won't even get to the z-buffer. you might want to try to give a really low opacity instead of absolute 0, or use an invisible texture (1x1 texture with invisible pixel) instead of setting material opacity. then it will render but won't change actual color. but these are hacks I would recommend finding a proper way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can render to the depth buffer only using the following pattern.

```
renderer.context.colorMask( false, false, false, false ); // don't update color buffer
renderer.render( scene1, camera ); // first scene

renderer.context.colorMask( true, true, true, true );
renderer.render( scene2, camera ); // second scene
```

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks for that - I haven't tested it, but it looks perfect